# Angular 2 Conditional Template?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a conditional template for a webpage that may use a different grid component depending on the id that was passed in

The webpages are setup like this

`www.mywebpage.com/referenceGrid/85`

or 
`www.mywebpage.com/referencePage/75`

Im listening to the page change `id` through `params` service

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.params.subscribe(
    (params: Params) => {
      this.pageid = params['id'];
      this.gridData = [];
    }
  );
}
```

They both share the same `component.ts` file. Lets call it **base.component.ts**.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-griddata',
  template: `
      <div [ngSwitch]="isCertainId">
        <template [ngSwitchCase]="true"> ${require('./specialId.component.html')} </template>
        <template ngSwitchDefault> ${require('./default.component.html')} </template>
      </div>`
      ],
})
```

I use `ViewChildren` to find the grid. They are both called `#grid`

```js
public isCertainId: boolean = false;
@ViewChildren('grid')
public childrenComponent: QueryList<GridComponent>;
  private grid: GridComponent;
```

The child cant be found until `ngAfterViewInit` so I call it here

```js
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.isCertainId = (this.pageid === '85' || this.pageid === '16');
  this.childrenComponent.changes.subscribe((comps: QueryList<GridComponent>) => {
    this.grid = comps.first;
  }
 });   
}
```

This works fine on initial screen load, however if the user selects a different webpage( pageid 85 to pageid 75) the template conditional statement doesn't get hit again as both pages use the same component.ts

How can I get that `[ngSwitch]` to be hit on a different page load?

Comment: how about you listen to the url changes through `Params` service, and change `isCertainId` accordingly?

Comment: Yea that is what I am doing

Comment: can you add the routes here ?

Comment: I've updated the question with the params service to show how I am getting the page Id. The issue is the template is not reloading. I need that conditional statement to be hit everytime the pageid changes

Comment: you either create a service to communicate between the child and the parent components, or you listen to the route changes in the component that defines `isCertainId `